# Не установились плагины Flutter и Dart в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Фактически в плагинах они имеются[image: 1]
Но flutter doctor их не видит[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Что делать?

Comment: Извините, если скажу крамольную вещь, но можно ничего не делать, если Вам это не мешает и сами плагины работают. Дело в том, что наличие Android Studio(или его плагинов) не является абсолютной необходимостью.

Вы можете удалить их(кажется, это пункт из выпадающего меню вверху-справа на скриншоте) и установить заново, если в этом есть необходимость.

Comment: @dut все заработало. правда непонятно каким образом. flutter doctor до сих пор сидит в танке :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В последних версиях Android Studio также проявилась эта "проблема". Судя по issue изменились пути расположения:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67986

Решение для macOS:

```
ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.1
```

Для Windows:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir=<#Путь к Android Studio#>
```

Или можно переключиться на `flutter channel dev` – здесь проблема уже исправлена "из коробки".

А можно проигнорировать, так как на работу это никак не влияет и скоро будет исправлено.